# Api limits / spam

Tags: twitter

I'm developing a website which listens a hashtag. When a user uses that hashgag, **and is currently following us** we send him a tweet saying something like "I've read that tweet and saved it".

So, would this be considered as spam? We've a limit programmed, for 8 tweets each 10 minutes (48 tweets / hour maximum)

This is the code we're using:

```
if(!$twitter->get("friendships/exists", array("screen_name_a" => $social_twitter->getScreenName(), "screen_name_b" => "our_twitter_acc"))){
  continue;
 }
```

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the Twitter API documentation

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

> Unauthenticated calls are permitted 150 requests per hour.
>   Unauthenticated calls are measured against the public facing IP of the
>   server or device making the request. OAuth calls are permitted 350
>   requests per hour and are measured against the oauth_token used in the
>   request.

So you should be absolutely fine